# all apps that use native code must provide a 64-bit version in addition to the 32-bit version in order to publish an update

Tags: android

"all apps that use native code must provide a 64-bit version in addition to the 32-bit version in order to publish an update". need some clarity like if I set my min SDK to 5.0, will my problem will solve?

Comment: Yes you need to provide 64-bit native (C/C++) code from Aug 1, 2019 onward. No, different minSDK will not change that requirement. What is your problem?

Answer (score 1):

`Build --> Analyze APK...` (Choose your APK)

Focus on **lib** folder.

If you have used a library that uses C / C ++ codes;

For 64-bit support, we need `arm64-v8a`, `x86_64` and `mips64` folders. (or other processor architectures).